# scrollview and expandablelistview cut

Tags: android, scrollview, expandablelistview, cut

I have a scrollview, inside a LinearLayout and inside a expandablelistview. But expandablelistview is cut below. But if I remove the scrollview, the expandablelistview looks good. This is my code:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
         android:fillViewport="true"
        >

<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/fondo"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

     <ExpandableListView
        android:id="@+id/lvExp"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    </ExpandableListView>...
```

What I can do? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
*//make height to fill parent
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" //make height to fill parent
         android:fillViewport="true"
        >
<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/fondo"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
     <ExpandableListView
        android:id="@+id/lvExp"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </ExpandableListView>...*
```